# Table in the shape of an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Is it possible (and not too difficult) to draw a table in the shape of an arrow? I think it's best explained giving an [example](http://www.12manage.com/images/picture_porter_value_chain.gif):

[image]

I'd like to draw a table almost exactly like this. However, the 2nd, 3rd and 4th row don't have to be like that but can be just regular cells.

Is it possible to draw this easily or should I just make it in a vector program and import it in my LaTeXfile as a picture?

Comment: What is the reason to use the arrow shape? Why not only a vertical text on the last two cells?

Comment: @Sigur: I'm guessing that it is meant to give a sense of 'flow' to the table.  Even though I don't really get why it is used in this particular case, I think it is a good question in general.  gieldl, I am sure someone will come by with a TikZ approach.

Comment: This is just a very common way of describing value chains, used in economics and business structures. It's pretty much always in exactly this shape. For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_chain

Answer (score 70, accepted):

One possibility using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mat) [table]
{
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
};

% horizontal rules
\foreach \row in {2,3,4}
  \draw (mat-\row-1.north west) -- (mat-\row-6.north east);
\draw[ultra thick] (mat-8-1.south west) -- (mat-8-5.south east);
\draw[ultra thick] (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-1-5.north east);
\draw[ultra thick] (mat-5-1.north west) -- (mat-5-6.north east);

% vertical rules
\draw[ultra thick] (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-8-1.south west);
\foreach \col in {2,3,4,5}
{  \draw (mat-5-\col.north west) -- (mat-8-\col.south west);
    \draw[dash pattern=on 2pt off 1.5pt] (mat-2-\col.north west) -- (mat-5-\col.south west);
}
%\draw[dashed] (mat-2-5.north west) -- (mat-5-5.south west);

% The labels
\node at (mat-1-3) {Firm Infrastructure};
\node[fill=white] at (mat-2-3) {Human Resources Management};
\node[fill=white] at (mat-3-3) {Technology Development};
\node[fill=white,inner xsep=8pt] at (mat-4-3) {Procurement};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-1) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Inbound Logistics}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-2) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Operations \\\mbox{}}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-3) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Outbound Logistics}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-4) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Marketing \& Sales}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-5) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Service \\\mbox{}}};
\node[rotate = 90] at ([xshift=-52pt]mat-3-1.north) {SUPPORT ACTIVITIES};
\node at ([yshift=-19pt,xshift=-0.5cm]mat-8-3.south) {PRIMARY ACTIVITIES};

% Erase some visible lines outside the arrow
\fill[white] (mat-1-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-1-6.north east) -- cycle;

% Draw the arrow tip
\draw[fill=white,draw=black,ultra thick] (mat-1-5.north) -- (mat-5-6.north) -- (mat-8-5.south) -- (mat-8-5.east|-mat-8-5.south east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-1-5.east|-mat-1-5.north west) -- cycle;

% The slanted "Margin" labels
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with \node[transform shape] {Margin};}]
\path[postaction={decorate}] 
  ( $ (mat-1-5.north)!0.5!(mat-1-5.north east) $ ) -- ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ );
\path[postaction={decorate}] 
  ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ ) -- ( $ (mat-8-5.south)!0.5!(mat-8-5.south east) $ );
\end{scope}

% The braces
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=6pt}]
  (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-5-1.north west);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=6pt}]
  (mat-8-1.south west) -- (mat-8-5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a little variation, adding some color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\definecolor{colone}{RGB}{209,220,204}
\definecolor{coltwo}{RGB}{204,222,210}
\definecolor{colthree}{RGB}{207,233,232}
\definecolor{colfour}{RGB}{248,243,214}
\definecolor{colfive}{RGB}{245,238,197}
\definecolor{colsix}{RGB}{243,235,179}
\definecolor{colseven}{RGB}{241,231,163}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mat) [table]
{
|[fill=colfour]| & |[fill=colfour]| & |[fill=colfour]| & |[fill=colfour]| & |[fill=colfour]| &  \\
|[fill=colfive]| & |[fill=colfive]| & |[fill=colfive]| & |[fill=colfive]| & |[fill=colfive]| &  \\
|[fill=colsix]| & |[fill=colsix]| & |[fill=colsix]| & |[fill=colsix]| & |[fill=colsix]| & |[fill=colsix]| \\
|[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| \\
|[fill=colone]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colthree]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colone]| & |[fill=colone]|  \\
|[fill=colone]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colthree]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colone]| & |[fill=colone]|  \\
|[fill=colone]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colthree]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colone]| & \\
|[fill=colone]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colthree]| & |[fill=coltwo]| & |[fill=colone]| &  \\
};

% horizontal rules
\foreach \row in {2,3,4}
  \draw[white] (mat-\row-1.north west) -- (mat-\row-6.north east);
\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-1-6.north east);
\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-5-1.north west) -- (mat-5-6.north east);

% vertical rules
\foreach \col in {2,3,4,5}
  \draw[white] (mat-5-\col.north west) -- (mat-8-\col.south west);

% The labels
\node[fill=colfour] at (mat-1-3) {Firm Infrastructure};
\node[fill=colfive] at (mat-2-3) {Human Resources Management};
\node[fill=colsix] at (mat-3-3) {Technology Development};
\node[fill=colseven] at (mat-4-3) {Procurement};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-1) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Inbound Logistics}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-2) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Operations \\\mbox{}}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-3) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Outbound Logistics}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-4) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Marketing \& Sales}};
\node at ([yshift=-10pt]mat-6-5) {\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Service \\\mbox{}}};
\node[rotate = 90] at ([xshift=-52pt]mat-3-1.north) {SUPPORT ACTIVITIES};
\node at ([yshift=-19pt,xshift=-0.5cm]mat-8-3.south) {PRIMARY ACTIVITIES};

% Erase some visible lines outside the arrow
\fill[white] (mat-1-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-1-6.north east) -- cycle;
\fill[white] (mat-8-5.north east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-8-6.north east) -- cycle;

% Draw the arrow tip
\shade[top color=colfour!70,bottom color=colfour!70,middle color=colseven,draw=white,ultra thick] 
  (mat-1-5.north) -- (mat-5-6.north) -- (mat-8-5.south) -- 
  (mat-8-5.south east) -- (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-8-5.south east) -- 
  (mat-5-6.north east) -- (mat-1-5.north east) -- cycle;

% The slanted "Margin" labels
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with \node[transform shape] {Margin};}]
\path[postaction={decorate}] 
  ( $ (mat-1-5.north)!0.5!(mat-1-5.north east) $ ) -- ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ );
\path[postaction={decorate}] 
  ( $ (mat-5-6.north)!0.5!(mat-5-6.north east) $ ) -- ( $ (mat-8-5.south)!0.5!(mat-8-5.south east) $ );
\end{scope}

% The braces
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=6pt}]
  (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-5-1.north west);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=6pt}]
  (mat-8-1.south west) -- (mat-8-5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this diagram could be a candidate for addition into the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram package

Comment: small niggle ... i think the ticks at the horizontal rules between lines 2, 3, and 4 on the original graphic (really "interrupted" extensions of the vertical rules in the bottom half) are there to indicate that the activities in these lines comprise the same components as shown in the bottom half.  omitting these little signals could imply a more "unitary" structure.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're right. I've added the interrupted extensions. Thanks!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina such a nice end result.

Comment: Nice +1. -I am thinking that it might be possible to make a 'normal' table, and only use TikZ to append the arrow. -in that way the look from other tables is preserved. I do not know how to that myself. -it involves exact anchor points, and line widths.

Comment: I had to hand in the assignment before I saw this answer but still, this is crazy. Thanks a lot for doing this! I'm sure lots of people will benefit from this

Comment: @gieldl You're welcome! I updated my answer providing a version using colors, similar to the image in Wikipedia you linked to.

Comment: That is one of the most beautiful figures I've seen. Very clean and crisp.

Comment: This is great! To quickly add your own details into the table, you can now [open in for editing online in writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/docs?template=arrow-shaped-table)

Comment: Amazing! However, the arrow is to wide. It should start further to the right, but end at the same spot. Or start at the same and end further left.

Comment: Minor problem in the top right (yellow version). There is a small step between `Firm Infrastructure` and `Margin`. -so the top edge is not straight.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen you're right. I've fixed the problem in my updated answer. Thanks for noticing the problem!

Comment: Great answer! I added your example to the [TeXample TikZ gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/arrow-table/).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Great! Thanks! I liked your modifications.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz The code for the matrix that you kindly posted in `TeXample.net` won't compile with PGF/TikZ version 3.0. I changed the code here to make it work with the new version, so I think the changes would also have to be made in the example in `TeXample.net`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you! I updated the TeXample file too. I noticed it still works with PGF 2.10 as well, and the code looks better.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Thanks! Yes, this newer version is clearer.